# The Healthplan finder API stopped responding, where can I get support or more information?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

The API at http://finder.healthcare.gov/services/ has stopped responding. Previously it was returning the stated data very well. Where can I get support or more information about what's going on?

Comment: A new tag for healthcare.gov's finder API has been created right here on open data. If you are still having trouble with the API, please add this tag to your question or ask a new question using this link. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=healthcare-finder.

Comment: @Stu - what issue are you seeing? I'm seeing it return a "File not found" as the sole string in the body. It seems to be a bug - it only returns that when the `method` part of the URI is a valid method.

Answer (score 4):

First, verify that you've tested your script on a different system. Then I would proceed to:

- Calling HHS at 800-318-2596
- Trying a [live chat](https://www.healthcare.gov/help-center/)
- Leaving feedback on this dataset at the [Developers' Center](http://www.hhs.gov/developer/)
- Sending a tweet to [@healthcaregov](https://twitter.com/HealthCareGov)
- Leaving a post/send a message on their [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Healthcare.gov) page

Comment: Am I missing something about their FB page? I can't figure out how to send a message via that page...